# Subtract two hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Can the `hash` class be modified so that given two hashes, a new hash containing only keys that are present in one hash but not the other can be created?

E.g.:

```
h1 = {"Cat" => 100, "Dog" => 5, "Bird" => 2, "Snake" => 10}

h2 = {"Cat" => 100, "Dog" => 5, "Bison" => 30}

h1.difference(h2) = {"Bird" => 2, "Snake" => 10}
```

Optionally, the `difference` method could include any key/value pairs such that the key is present in both hashes but the value differs between them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `reject` method:

```
class Hash
  def difference(other)
    reject do |k,v|
      other.has_key? k
    end
  end
end
```

To only reject key/value pairs if the values are identical (as per [mallanaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639575/mallanaga)'s suggestion via a comment on my original answer, which I have deleted):

```
class Hash
  def difference(other)
    reject do |k,v|
      other.has_key?(k) && other[k] == v
    end
  end
end
```

---

Comment: Hm, I didn't realize that was the convention--must have skimmed that part of *Eloquent Ruby* a little too quickly.

Comment: Great book, but Mr. Olsen probably assumed readers knew about that.  If you liked that book, have a look at [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://www.amazon.com/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Pros/dp/1934356476/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1404920781&sr=8-1&keywords=metaprogramming+ruby).

Comment: Some readers may have thought `reject` returns an array, not a hash.  It is true that [Enumerable#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) returns an array and the class `Hash` includes the `Enumerable` module, but `Hash` also has the method [Hash#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject) which returns a hash and has precedence over the Enumerable `reject`.  Same for `select`.  Notice there are methods `Hash#reject!` and `Hash#select!`, but no corresponding `!` methods in the `Enumerable` module.

Comment: Nice one ! However this might not work on nested levels.

Comment: @PratikK.Shah That would be tricky; you'd need to carefully design the desired behavior.

Answer (score 16):

```
h1 = {"Cat" => 100, "Dog" => 5, "Bird" => 2, "Snake" => 10}
h2 = {"Cat" => 999, "Dog" => 5, "Bison" => 30}
```

**Case 1: keep all key/value pairs `k=>v` in `h1` for which there is no key `k` in `h2`**

This is one way:

```
h1.dup.delete_if { |k,_| h2.key?(k) }
  #=> {"Bird"=>2, "Snake"=>10}
```

This is another:

```
class Array
  alias :spaceship :<=>
  def <=>(o)
    first <=> o.first
  end
end

(h1.to_a - h2.to_a).to_h
  #=> {"Bird"=>2, "Snake"=>10}

class Array
  alias :<=> :spaceship
  remove_method(:spaceship)
end
```

**Case 2: keep all key/value pairs in `h1` that are not in `h2`**

All you need for this is:

```
(h1.to_a - h2.to_a).to_h
  #=> {"Cat"=>100, "Bird"=>2, "Snake"=>10}
```

[Array#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) was introduced in Ruby 2.0.  For earlier versions, use [Hash[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
h2.each_with_object(h1.dup){|(k, v), h| h.delete(k)}
```

Comment: The `each_with_object` method wasn't introduced until Ruby 1.9, and I doubt that's faster than my suggestion of `h1.reject{|k,v| h2.has_key? k}`.

Answer (score 0):

try using hashdiff gem.

```
diff=HashDiff.diff(h1,h2)
```

Comment: Could you provide some more details (and a link)? From http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/hashdiff/0.2.2 , it appears that this is doing something somewhat different. For one thing, it returns a list of lists, where each inner list has three elements, rather than a new hash. Also, it appears that if `h2` contains elements not in `h1`, these elements will be represented--which is **not** the case for a hash **subtraction** operation.

Answer (score 0):

For deep nesting you can add a bit of recursion, something like (untested)

```
class Hash
  def -(h2)
    raise ArgumentError unless h2.is_a?(Hash)
    h1 = dup
    h1.delete_if do |k, v|
      if v.is_a?(Hash) && h2[k].is_a?(Hash)
        h1[k] = v - h2[k]
        h1[k].blank?
      else
        h2[k] == v
      end
    end
   end
  end
end
```